# Apply GPO to single workgroup computer

Tags: group-policy

I have a GPO I've exported from Group Policy Editor on a domain controller. Is there a way to apply this policy to a computer that isn't connected to a domain at all? Just a one-time application of all the settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All the settings no, but doing the following will allow you to import those settings that can be imported

1) Export using the Group policy from the domain and save/copy it to the local machine

2) Grab this tool [Microsoft Security Compliance Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16776) which after install will give you LocalGPO.wsf

3) `cscript LocalGPO.wsf /path:C:\path to backup\{42ADD8FE-EDF6-479B-92C6-557343D8D090}`

The link for step 2 is the latest version but there is a lite/older version but depending on OS (which you don't mention) it may not work for you [LocalGPO (lite version)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/LocalGPOmsi-Excellent-MS-2593b2eb)

Comment: You should be able to apply all settings applicable to a non domain joined machine.

Comment: Once I get LocalGPO.wsf, can I used it on other machines without installing that tool?

Answer (score 0):

On a standalone computer you can only edit the *security* policy; all other sections in domain GPOs are just not available outside a domain environment.

However, you can replicate many GPO settings by changing the corresponding Registry keys.